# How to get all values in a form with Onchange attribute

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm trying to get all the values in a form when the user selects an option in the droplist. I'm using the Onchange attribute but I don't know how to send the all values to submitForm() via this attribute.

```
<input type="hidden" name="var1" value="..." />
<input type="hidden" name="var2" value="..." />
<input type="hidden" name="var3" value="..." />

<select name="var4" onchange="submitForm([var1 var2 var3 var4]);return false">
<option value="1">Choice 1</option>
<option value="2">Choice 2</option>

</select>
```

```
    <script>
    function submitForm(var1, var2, var3, var4)
    {
    var OAjax;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) OAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) OAjax = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    OAjax.open('POST',"return.php",true);
    OAjax.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
    if (OAjax.readyState == 4 && OAjax.status==200)
    {
      if (document.getElementById)
      {   
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML=''+OAjax.responseText+'';
      }     
    }
    }
    OAjax.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    OAjax.send(var1='+var1+'&var2='+var2'&var3='+var3'&var4='+var4);                 
    } 
    </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: It really does not matter.  When the submit event for a form gets fired, either by the submit button being clicked, or by firing the submit action some other way, all the elements get submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no jQuery used in your js method, I'm assuming you are not really using jQuery.

In that case

```
<select name="var4" onchange="submitForm();">
```

then

```
function submitForm() {
    //get the input elements by name and then read its value
    var OAjax, var1 = document.getElementsByName('var1')[0].value,
        var2 = document.getElementsByName('var2')[0].value,
        var3 = document.getElementsByName('var3')[0].value,
        var4 = document.getElementsByName('var4')[0].value;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) OAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) OAjax = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
    OAjax.open('POST', "return.php", true);
    OAjax.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (OAjax.readyState == 4 && OAjax.status == 200) {
            if (document.getElementById) {
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = '' + OAjax.responseText + '';
            }
        }
    }
    OAjax.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    //create a parma string using the input values
    OAjax.send('var1=' + var1 + '&var2=' + var2 '&var3=' + var3 '&var4=' + var4);
}
```

Comment: thx it works. Just, for those coming after, you forgot the char "+" after var2 and var3 in the OAjax.send(). And then it works all good. Thx